# Execute a for loop in parallel using CompletableFuture in Java and log the execution

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, completable-future

I have a for loop which I am trying to parallelize using CompletableFuture.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

What I have till now is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething());
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomethingElse());
}
```

I guess this serves the purpose but there is a requirement to print log just before the start and end of all the processing. If I do this:

```
log("Started doing things");
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething());
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomethingElse());
}
log("Ended doing things");
```

Does this guarantee that the second log statement will be printed once all the for loop is over since that is executing in a separate thread? If not, is there a way to do this without blocking the main thread?

Comment: Why do you want to use `CompletableFuture`? (It doesn't seem you use these objects outside the loop any more, so there is no need of doing it with `CompletableFuture`s.)

Comment: In order to ensure the loop has finished executing without blocking the main thread

Comment: Therefore you don't need a `CompletableFuture`. There are other mechanisms in Java that are better suited for this purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to collect all CompletableFutures and wait for their complete:

```
log("Started doing things");
List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomething()));
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomethingElse()));
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                 .thenRunAsync(() -> log("Ended doing things"));
```

Or when you use the ExecutorService:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
    } catch (InterruptedException) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log("Ended doing things");
});
```

Comment: Is `futures.foreach(CompletableFuture::join)` blocking? I don't want to block the main thread.

Comment: It is, but you can execute the join operations in an other thread if you want the main Thread to keep running.

Comment: So will adding this after the for loop work?
    ```CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
        log("Ended doing things");
    });```

Comment: It should, but you can also directly use CompletableFuture.allOf()

Comment: This is neat. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the second example using the `ExecutorService` as it doesn't work this way (`invokeAll` is a blocking call).

Comment: If you want to use an explicit `ExecutorService`, you can specify it as second argument to `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)`

Answer (score 8):

I suppose `CompletableFuture` is the wrong concept for your needs. If you want to execute an arbitrary number of similar tasks in parallel, the easiest thing is to use the method `invokeAll(...)` on an `ExecutionService`:

```
// First, create a list with all tasks you want to execute in parallel
List<Callable<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(10000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    // we need to create Callables, so if your doSomething method returns void, we have to convert it to a Callable using helper method from class Executors
    tasks.add(Executors.callable(this::doSomething));
}

// Then, create an executor service that can execute these tasks
// There are different executors you can choose from, I take one that has a fixed pool of threads
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

// Last but not least, call invokeAll to execute all tasks and wait for them to complete
executorService.invokeAll(tasks);

// This method will be called when all tasks have been completed successfully:
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: Is `invokeAll()` a blocking call? I don't want to block the main thread.

Comment: Yes it is. But you wrote that you want the second log statement to be called when all tasks have been finished. This is exactly what blocking is.

Comment: Maybe I could do that in a different thread itself?
I was using CompletableFuture because it has `thenRun()` which does not block the main thread.

Which would be the better way?

Comment: So you don't care about the thread that runs your second log statement?

Comment: No, I just want it to execute immediately after the for loop without blocking the main thread.

Comment: "No"? I mean: Is it important to you, *which* thread invokes the final operation (second log statement), or can it be *any* thread, as long as it is *after* all other tasks?

Comment: It can be any thread but since this snippet is a method call, I don't want the main thread to be blocked, that's all.

Comment: In this case you should go with the answer of kairaedsch