# It's possible cloning a WebDriver instance in order to execute some steps concurrently in a test case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm refactoring an automation tests framework implemented with *Java*, *Selenium*, *TestNG* and *Maven*. I'm currently trying to reduce the execution time of a test case which takes more than one hour for completing.

Reviewing the code I realized that I could execute some steps concurrently in order to reduce execution time. Although I know that `WebDriver` class isn't thread safe, therefore I'd like to open three new  instances of the web browser with the same previously page loaded in order to collect the required data concurrently.

**Question**

How could I achieve this?

Comment: one way I could think of, if there is data creation in testcase itself, seperate  data creation and actual testcase in 2 different files , execute data creation file as data setup job then execute actual testcases of those data use property file to input for data creation and use same to execute actual testcases so that you will get same data in testcase what was crated in setup job

Comment: You can try using CompletableFutures in JAVA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360559/execute-a-for-loop-in-parallel-using-completablefuture-in-java-and-log-the-execu

Comment: @RahulL thanks for the advice but the `WebDriver` class is not thread safe that's the main goal of my question

Comment: If you are going to create the separate instances then you can manage them using threadlocal and get separate instance in each thread . https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/ Here its TestNG method level thread but you may be able to use similar concept in CompletableFutures

Comment: @Rahul L And how could I keep the same state (same page loaded with the same data) of a previous WebDriver instance  in the new ones  ?

Comment: Same page loading in different instances would be very tricky.If some application has form with 4 tabs and one single login can be used in 4 separate browser then one can fill data in 4 tabs using 4 instances of driver.(one tab in one instance)It would only be possible if state is managed by application at server side.

Comment: How is WebDriver not thread safe? I use it all the time to run 40 browser instances with no issues. You should probably describe your scenario and what is taking an hour to complete so we can potentially help there. You can't spawn a "clone" of a browser instance from where it currently is, you'll have to start from a clean browser instance per WebDriver.

Comment: @JeffC https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek `You /can/ on the other hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.` which is what most people do and what I described above.